# How can we ignore some nested fields while comparing two responses in karate, i am using "contains deep" for the comparison

Tags: karate, contains

I want to compare two nested json response, so i am using "contains deep". But while comparison i want to ingnore some fields(skip comparison on those fields).

Example: I want to ignore the state field while comparing both response given below.

```
Scenario1:
    * def response1 = { id: 1, name: 'John', address: { city: 'New York', state: 'NY' } }
    * def response2 = { id: 1, name: 'John', address: { city: 'California', state: 'CA' } }

    * match response1 contains deep response2

# Note: My requirement is tp show difference of city only as state i want to ignore in the karate report
```

```
Scenario2:
    * def response1 = { id: 1, name: 'John', address: { city: 'New York', state: 'NY' } }
    * def response2 = { id: 1, name: 'John', address: { city: 'New York', state: 'CA' } }

    * match response1 contains deep response2

# Note: My requirement is to show no difference at all as the state node should be ignored in the karate report.
```

I am not sure what exactly should i try here for ignoring the field. Please help here.

Answer (score 0):

> tp show difference of city only in the karate report

Sorry, Karate doesn't work like that. Teams use it for [schema validation like this](https://github.com/karatelabs/karate?tab=readme-ov-file#fuzzy-matching), and by the way, this is the answer to your "Scenario 2".

```
* match response contains deep { address: { city: '#string' } }
```

What you are asking for can be done by code. Or you are welcome to contribute code to Karate.

Here is how you can re-write Scenario 2:

```
  * def response1 = { id: 1, name: 'John', address: { city: 'New York', state: 'NY' } }
  * def response2 = { id: 1, name: 'John', address: { city: 'New York', state: 'CA' } }
  * response2.address.state = '#string'
  * match response1 == response2
```

Comment: I think ignoring fields feature should be there in karate while comparison. 
Because suppose there is current timestamp is stored in a nested response, timestamp will always be different, so we should ignore that node while comparison. Timestamp difference should not fail the testcases as it is mostly irrelevant while comparison.

Comment: @rajeevranjan have you read the documentation. things like `#string` and even `#ignore` are there specifically for the timestamp use-case you mentioned.